# Django many to one api for React js

Tags: reactjs, django, model, many-to-one

I am really new in Django and it relationships. I have made one small Ecommerce models. In my models there are `customer`, `products`, `product-tags` and `orders`. `product` and `product-tags` have many to many relationship. In `Order` model `many-to-one` relationship with `customer` and `Product`. I think my relationship model looks good. I have made api end points for `React` frontend. Where I want to pull specific single customer's specific product order. I saw in Django documentation `_set.all()` and but still I could not able to get the customer specific order. In my React frontend the [order-list-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbYZv.png) and [customer-list-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFcYq.png) looks like this.

I want to pull customer's order list. But could not able to do that.

**I share my code in [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/alak/django-react)**

**This is django models**

```
# ##################
# ##### MODELS #####
# ##################
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null= True)
    email =  models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    date_created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tag(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY=(
         ('Indoor', 'Indoor'),
         ('Outdoor', 'Outdoor'),

            )

    name= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price= models.FloatField(null=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank= True)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags= models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS =(
         ('Pending', 'Pending'),
         ('Out of delivery', 'Out of delivery'),
         ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),

            )
    status= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,choices= STATUS)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    customer= models.ForeignKey(Customer, null= True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product, null= True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
```

**This is my serializers**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ["name"]

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags =  TagSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name','id', 'tags']

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['name', 'id', 'email', 'phone']


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerSerializer()
    product = ProductSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['status', 'customer', 'product']
```

**This is my `views'` api end points and `CRUD` method**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from .serializers import *
from .models import *


@api_view(['GET'])
def apiOverview(request):
    api_urls ={
        'List': '/customer-list/',
        'Detail View': '/customer-detail/<str:pk>/',
        'Create':'/customer-create/',
        'Update': '/customer-update/<str:pk>/',
        'Delete': '/customer-delete/<str:pk>/',
        'Order List': '/order-list/'
    }
    return Response(api_urls)


@api_view(['GET'])
def orderList(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    serializer = OrderSerializer(orders, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def orderCreate(request):
    serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def customerList(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer = CustomerSerializer(customers, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
def customerDetail(request, pk):
    customers = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = customers.order_set.all() // IN here I tried order_set.all()
    serializer = CustomerSerializer(customers, many=False)

    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
def customerCreate(request):
    serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def customerUpdate(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = CustomerSerializer(instance=customer, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['DELETE'])
def customerDelete(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    customer.delete()

    return Response("Item deleted")
```

Comment: you are returning customer not orders in that api

Comment: Show me what query i am doing wrong?